# python code to filtering data contains on the file and store it into the dictionary

Tags: python

i have one file and contain some data

```
 Net Name:  VDD
 Pin Name:  VDD
 Instance Name:  ld_slice_logic_wrap_inst/ld_slice_logic_top_inst/ld_clk_gen_top_inst/ld_wdqs_clk_gen

 Layer/Via#  PGResistor  Resistance(cumulative) Ohm  Voltage_Drop(cumulative) V  Length 
 VSRC       N 0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00 3.7865e-03 3.7865e-03  0  144.43150,550.00000   
 AP         N 1.0000e-06 1.0000e-06 0.0000e+00 3.7865e-03  0.000100000001  144.43150,550
 AP         N 3.1474e-03 3.1484e-03 5.6028e-06 3.7921e-03  6.8432998  144.43200,550.0000
 AP         N 1.0000e-06 3.1494e-03 0.0000e+00 3.7921e-03  0.000200000003  144.43200,543
 AP         N 1.9433e-03 5.0927e-03 1.1802e-05 3.8039e-03  4.1663999  144.43200,543.1565
 AP         N 2.5653e-03 7.6580e-03 1.7583e-05 3.8215e-03  5.5001001  144.43200,538.9900
 AP         N 1.0137e-02 1.7795e-02 7.0572e-05 3.8921e-03  8.851  144.43200,533.49000   
 AP         N 2.1164e-02 3.8959e-02 1.5050e-04 4.0426e-03  16.0295  144.43200,524.63900 
 AP         N 9.9838e-07 3.8960e-02 0.0000e+00 4.0426e-03  0.054  128.40250,524.63900   
 RV         N 3.3405e-02 7.2365e-02 2.3925e-04 4.2818e-03  2.7  128.40250,524.69300   
 M15        N 9.9838e-07 7.2366e-02 0.0000e+00 4.2818e-03  0.6985  128.40250,524.69300  
 M15        N 1.0580e-01 1.7817e-01 4.3488e-04 4.7167e-03  14.947  127.70400,524.69300  
 VIA14      N 8.8155e-03 1.8698e-01 5.1737e-05 4.7684e-03  0.324  127.70400,539.64000   
 M14        N 3.5033e-02 2.2201e-01 1.1855e-04 4.8870e-03  4.96  127.70400,539.64000   
 M14        N 1.6951e-01 3.9153e-01 1.3857e-03 6.2727e-03  24  132.66400,539.64000   
 M9         N 9.5367e-07 6.2670e+00 0.0000e+00 7.4605e-03  0.26  187.49200,516.86300 
      
 Layer/Via  Resistance(Ohm)  Voltage_Drop(V)  R_Cumulative(Ohm)  Vdrop_Cummulative(V) 
 VSRC        0.0000e+00  3.7865e-03  0.0000e+00  3.7865e-03 
 AP          3.8960e-02  2.5606e-04  3.8960e-02  4.0426e-03 
 RV          3.3405e-02  2.3925e-04  7.2365e-02  4.2818e-03 
 M15         1.0580e-01  4.3488e-04  1.7817e-01  4.7167e-03 
 VIA14       8.8155e-03  5.1737e-05  1.8698e-01  4.7684e-03 
 M9          2.2392e+00  5.8532e-05  6.2670e+00  7.4605e-03 

 Net Name:  VSS
 Pin Name:  VSS
 Instance Name:  ld_slice_logic_wrap_inst/ld_slice_logic_top_inst/ld_clk_gen_top_inst/ld_wdqs_clk_gen

 Layer/Via#  PGResistor  Resistance(cumulative) Ohm  Voltage_Drop(cumulative) V  Length 
 VSRC       N 0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00 3.7865e-03 3.7865e-03  0  144.43150,550.00000   
 AP         N 1.0000e-06 1.0000e-06 0.0000e+00 3.7865e-03  0.000100000001  144.43150,550
 AP         N 3.1474e-03 3.1484e-03 5.6028e-06 3.7921e-03  6.8432998  144.43200,550.0000
 AP         N 1.0000e-06 3.1494e-03 0.0000e+00 3.7921e-03  0.000200000003  144.43200,543
 AP         N 1.9433e-03 5.0927e-03 1.1802e-05 3.8039e-03  4.1663999  144.43200,543.1565
 AP         N 2.5653e-03 7.6580e-03 1.7583e-05 3.8215e-03  5.5001001  144.43200,538.9900
 AP         N 1.0137e-02 1.7795e-02 7.0572e-05 3.8921e-03  8.851  144.43200,533.49000   
 AP         N 2.1164e-02 3.8959e-02 1.5050e-04 4.0426e-03  16.0295  144.43200,524.63900 
 AP         N 9.9838e-07 3.8960e-02 0.0000e+00 4.0426e-03  0.054  128.40250,524.63900   
 RV         N 3.3405e-02 7.2365e-02 2.3925e-04 4.2818e-03  2.7  128.40250,524.69300   
 M15        N 9.9838e-07 7.2366e-02 0.0000e+00 4.2818e-03  0.6985  128.40250,524.69300  
 M15        N 1.0580e-01 1.7817e-01 4.3488e-04 4.7167e-03  14.947  127.70400,524.69300  
 VIA14      N 8.8155e-03 1.8698e-01 5.1737e-05 4.7684e-03  0.324  127.70400,539.64000   
 M14        N 3.5033e-02 2.2201e-01 1.1855e-04 4.8870e-03  4.96  127.70400,539.64000   
 M14        N 1.6951e-01 3.9153e-01 1.3857e-03 6.2727e-03  24  132.66400,539.64000   
 M9         N 9.5367e-07 6.2670e+00 0.0000e+00 7.4605e-03  0.26  187.49200,516.86300 
      
 Layer/Via  Resistance(Ohm)  Voltage_Drop(V)  R_Cumulative(Ohm)  Vdrop_Cummulative(V) 
 VSRC        0.0000e+00  3.7865e-03  0.0000e+00  3.7865e-03 
 AP          3.8960e-02  2.5606e-04  3.8960e-02  4.0426e-03 
 RV          3.3405e-02  2.3925e-04  7.2365e-02  4.2818e-03 
 M15         1.0580e-01  4.3488e-04  1.7817e-01  4.7167e-03 
 VIA14       8.8155e-03  5.1737e-05  1.8698e-01  4.7684e-03 
 M9          2.2392e+00  5.8532e-05  6.2670e+00  7.4655e-03
```

the file data will repeat with **Net Name** and **Pin Name** as **VDD,VSS,VDDA,VSSA. so on..**

I Want to skip the **DATA** after **Layer/Via#** till before **Layer/Via** and i want to consider only **M9** data after the Layer/Via with the last value **" eg: 7.4605e-03,7.4655e-03 "**

The logic i tried

```
def read_pin_file(filename):
  with open(filename, "r") as f:   
    flag_count = 0
    
    for line in f:
            result ={}
            pin_name = None 
            line = line.strip()
            if line[:3] == "Pin":
                pin_name = line.split(" ")[3]
                result[pin_name] = {"M9": None}
                 
            if line.startswith("Layer/Via "):
                 flag_count +=1
                  
            if flag_count == 1:
                line = line.strip()
                if line[:2] == "M9":
                  # M9 = line.split(" ")[14]
                   result[pin_name]["M9"] = line.split(" ")[14]
                  # print(M9)
                   flag_count = 0
                                                                
read_pin_file("inst_1.txt")
```

Expected output

```
{'Pin_Name': 'VDD', 'Net_Name': 'VSS', 'M9': '7.4605e-03'}
{'Pin_Name': 'VSS', 'Net_Name': 'VSS', 'M9': '7.4655e-03'}
```

may I know what is wrong with this code? I am getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lss1.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(read_pin_file("inst_1.txt"))  
  File "lss1.py", line 20, in read_pin_file
    result[pin_name]["M9"] = line.split(" ")[14]
KeyError: None
```

can anyone please guide me to come out of this?

Comment: It appears that your function `read_pin_file` reads one of the two sections of your input data file.  It returns as soon as it finds the first `M9` value.  What makes you think that the code in that function will run twice and somehow return a different result each time?  I think you need a loop in that function, and a way of collecting each `M9` value so that you can return a list of those values.

Comment: @CryptoFool I got it, what you are telling.  once the mentioned data(M9) is received, it will exit from the function, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  You need some sort of loop in there, and a way to return multiple results.

Comment: how can i read all the "M9" present in the file, the expected output that i mentioned here.

Comment: @CryptoFool any suggetion ?